# Using react-native-router-flux vs nativebase

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-router-flux, native-base

I read https://blog.nativebase.io/the-caveats-of-using-navigator-in-react-native-9547d99172ce#.cghvxk1mo

using react-native-router-flux for navigator 
but when I using it with nativebase. Component of nativebase not active

```js
/**
* Sample React Native App
* https://github.com/facebook/react-native
* @flow
*/

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry,Text,View,Navigator } from 'react-native';
import { Container,Header,Content,Title,Badge,Tabs,Button,Icon} from 'native-base';
import { Router, Scene } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import Home from './component/Home';
import MyScene from './component/MyScene';

class CookApp extends Component {
  //State la bien dung de luu giu trang thai. Con props la bien dung de trung chuyen du lieu, ham giua cac component
  //dat ten class phai viet hoa dau, ten file phai trung file class
  render() {
    return (
      <Router hideTabBar={true}>
          <Scene key="PageOne" component={Home} title="Home" initial={true} />
          <Scene key="pageTwo" component={MyScene} title="MyScene" />
      </Router>
    );
  }
}


AppRegistry.registerComponent('CookApp', () => CookApp);
```

file: Home.js

```js
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';
import { Container,Header,Content,Title,Badge,Tabs,Button,Icon,Input} from 'native-base';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';

export default class Home extends Component {

  render() {
    const goToPageTwo = () => Actions.pageTwo({text: 'Hello World!'});
    return (
      <Header>
        <Button>
          <Icon name='ios-arrow-back' />
        </Button>
        <Title>CookApp</Title>
        <Button>
          <Icon name='ios-menu' />
        </Button>
      </Header>
      <Container>
        <Content>
          <Button transparent onPress={Actions.pageTwo}>
            go to pageTwo
          </Button>
          <View style={{margin: 128}}>
            <Text onPress={goToPageTwo}>This is PageOne!</Text>
          </View>
        </Content>
      </Container>
    )
  }
}
```

File : My scene.js

```js
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';
import { Container,Header,Content,Title,Badge,Tabs,Button,Icon} from 'native-base';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
export default class MyScene extends Component {
  // static propTypes = {
  //   title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  //   onForward: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  //   onBack: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  // }
  render() {
    return (
      // <Container>
      //   <Header>
      //     <Button transparent onPress={this.props.onBack}>
      //       <Icon name='ios-arrow-back' />
      //     </Button>
      //     <Title> { this.props.title }</Title>
      //     <Button transparent onPress={this.props.onForward}>
      //       <Icon name='ios-menu' />
      //     </Button>
      //   </Header>
      //
      //   <Content>
      //     <Button transparent onPress = {this.deleteText}>
      //       <Icon name='ios-home' />
      //     </Button>
      //   </Content>
      // </Container>
      <View style={{margin: 128}}>
      <Text>This is PageTwo!</Text>
      <Text>{this.props.text}</Text>
    </View>
    )
  }
}
```

When running app. Component of nativeBase not active.

Anyone used nativeBase with react-native-router-flux. please give me an example!
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

NativeBase has nothing to do with `react-native-router-flux`. So that must be simple and straight forward.

[Native-Starter-Kit](https://github.com/start-react/native-starter-kit) (NSK) previously implemented NativeBase with `react-native-router-flux`.
Due to enhancing features of [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/), NSK replaced react-native-router-flux with React Native Navigator.

Also, very soon NSK will implement Navigator Experimental.

Comment: @MaheshKarthu [NSK](https://github.com/start-react/native-starter-kit) is upgraded with latest of NativeBase and React Native along with React Native Router Flux

Comment: here is the latest update example https://github.com/vijaychouhan-rails/AllInOne/

Answer (score 0):

find the latest example at https://github.com/vijaychouhan-rails/AllInOne/

I hope this will give you better understanding how to use `NativeBase with react-native-router-flux`